# Apache commons csv how to edit specific column from csv file

Tags: csv, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

I can read the csv file with the below code,

```
Reader inRead = new FileReader("testfile.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(inRead);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Name");
}
```

But, I want to append last name with "ABC" and update the same file. is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Apache commons CSV doesn't support modifying a file while reading and that is arguably unadvisable. Consider reading the file and then overwrite it with the modified version. If it's important for performance to modify the file while reading have a look at `RandomAccessFile`

Comment: Thanks Manos. I'm now using open csv for modification.